# URL Parsing and get the part of the url using smarty

Tags: php, parsing, smarty

By using the below php code i can able to fetch the current url and perform parsing and get a part of the string.But this code is not is not supporting in my smarty template file.The smarty code which i have converted is not working properly.

**php code:**

```
<?php

$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$url_path=$url;

$parsed = parse_url($url);

$path = explode('/', $parsed['path']);

$resulturl =  $parsed['scheme'] . '//' . $parsed['host'] .'/'. $path[1] . '/';

$outurl = $path[1];

 ?> 

if ($outurl == "album") { 
    <h6>Sample text one </h6>
 }
else
{ 
    <h6>Sample text two </h6>
}
```

**Smarty code:**

```
{php} 

$url={$smarty.server.HTTP_HOST}{$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI}

$url_path=$url;

$parsed = parse_url($url);

$path = explode('/', $parsed['path']);

$resulturl =  $parsed['scheme'] . '//' . $parsed['host'] .'/'. $path[1] . '/';

$outurl = $path[1];

{/php}

{if $outurl == 'album'}
     <h6>Sample text one </h6>
{else}
     <h6>Sample text two </h6>
{/if}
```

Comment: Smarty is  templating language. This is not templating logic. Perform this type of logic 1st and pass simple data to the template.

Answer (score 1):

You do it wrong way. Smarty is for separating PHP actions from displaying. What you should do is simple:

PHP file:

```
<?php

$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$url_path=$url;

$parsed = parse_url($url);

$path = explode('/', $parsed['path']);

$resulturl =  $parsed['scheme'] . '//' . $parsed['host'] .'/'. $path[1] . '/';

$outurl = $path[1];

$smarty->assign('outurl', $outurl);
```

Smarty template file:

```
{if $outurl == 'album'}
     <h6>Sample text one </h6>
{else}
     <h6>Sample text two </h6>
{/if}
```

Using `{php}` tag in Smarty templates is deprecated now and in current version you can use it only using BC class and not the standard class. In your case I don't see any point to use this tag in Smarty template because you can simple do it in PHP file and pass `$outurl` to template file.

Comment: I have tried the same  in my prestashop site but the php code is commented out and cant able to get $outurl.Hence functionality is not working.@Marcin Nabialek

Comment: There's no way it doesn't work. Have you checked value of $outurl before assigning it into Smarty? You should test the code using    `$smarty->assign('outurl', 'album');` or `$smarty->assign('outurl', 'album2');` It works fine so your problem is probably somewhere else

Comment: I think i have done mistake in passing $outurl value.How to pass the outurl value to template file?Where i need to place this code $smarty->assign('outurl', 'album'); @Marcin Nabialek

Comment: @user3489161  First you should of course create Smarty object, but you can do this assignment right after you calculate the value - as in my answer. If it doesn't work probably you do also something else in your code or you use some Framework and without full code it's impossible to tell what you are doing wrong

Comment: Hi i am getting the undefined index outurl error.I have placed the php code in a php file of my prestashop root folder.Now my problem is if i have include the php file inside my header.tpl php is not working.So i am in need to know how to pass the value alone to header.tpl file.@ Marcin Nabialek

Comment: You should not include file in Smarty. You should include this PHP file in other PHP file.

Comment: I have placed the php code given by you in a php file and include that php file in my prestashop theme folders index.php file and also added the smarty if condition code in template file present inside a module folder.still i am getting undefined inded out url error.I think there is some issue with this smarty syntax $smarty->assign('outurl', 'album'); @Marcin Nabialek

Comment: I have one query why we are using same variable $outurl in php smarty code $smarty->assign('outurl', $outurl); and in template code {if $outurl == 'album'}. What is the code to pass the smarty object value to a template file? @ Marcin Nabialek

Comment: `$smarty->assign('outurl', $outurl);` - that's the code. So maybe you use outurl variable somewhere else and should change it into `$smarty->assign('myouturl', $outurl);` and in Smarty template use also `{if $myouturl == 'album'}` ?

Comment: Yes i have tried the same.Now the issue is the smarty object value we are having in php file is not passing to the template file.Is there any other code to pass the smarty object value present in php file to a prestashop tpl file.@Marcin Nabialek

Comment: Sorry, it's impossible to help you this way. You should close this question and create new one with detailed explanation and code examples